# Jquery and create html on the fly

Tags: jquery

I try to show html code in the fly using `jquery` and it´s the first time I try but I think I have something wrong in my concepts.

Here is my code:

```
<script>    
jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
   jQuery("#popup").click(function() {    
      $("<div class=foo id=bar style='color:white;bgcolor:blue;font-size:12pt'></div>")
   });        
});    
</script>
```

The problem it´s how show this html code , i think show when click but no

Comment: Missing quotes around foo and bar. Should be: `$("<div class='foo' id='bar' style='color:white;bgcolor:blue;font-size:12pt'></div>")`

Comment: @MichaelPeterson Although it is silly to not have quotes, they are not required

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have created the elements behind the scenes and haven't told jQuery where to put the elements so you you can tell jQuery where to put the elements with either `html();` or `append();`. Like this example.

```
  jQuery("#popup").click(function() {    
      $(this).append("<div class=foo id=bar style='color:white; bgcolor:blue; font-size:12pt'></div>")
  });
```

A better practice would be to create your elements like this.

```
$('#popup').click(function() {
    $(this).append(
       $('<div>', {
          'class': 'foo',
          id: 'bar',
          css: {
             color: 'white',
             background: 'blue',
             fontSize: '12pt'
          }
       });
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use .append()

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery("#popup").click(function() {

$("#SomeDIv").append("<div class=foo id=bar style='color:white;bgcolor:blue;font-size:12pt'></div>")



});


});

</script>
```

Check this link

http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/2CueT/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#popup").click(function() {
        $("#bar").show();
    });
    jQuery('body').bind('click keyup', function () {
            $("#bar").hide();
        });
});

</script>
<div class="foo" id="bar" style='color:white;bgcolor:blue;font-size:12pt;display:none;'></div>
```